# Is hitting the database required for current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, authentication

I've been following a tutorial that sets up simple user authentication. The following code is used to determine if a user is logged in:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

If all I wanted to do was to ensure the user is logged in (and don't require anything from the user model), could I use something like:

```
def is_user_logged_in
   true if session[:user_id]
end
```

This way I wouldn't have to hit the database if all I wanted to do was check if the user is logged in. Does that look correct? And if so, are there any security concerns?

Comment: The main concern here is that you won't be able to determine whether user account has been  removed or not. Apart of that it should be fine (can be written as `!!session[:user_id]` though).

Comment: and whats the problem with a single sql query?

Comment: I would say that yes, you can get by with just the user's id, but at some point you're going to want to keep referring to the actual user record, so you might as well just do that from the start, rather than some misguided attempt to make your app more "efficient" by making one less sql query per page load.

Answer (score 2):

The `current_user` helper was popularized by [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) (if you didn't know).

In fact, the `user_signed_in?` method was also [popularized by devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7df57d5081f9884849ca15e4fde179ef164a575f/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L119):

```
def user_signed_in?
    !!current_user
end
```

I looked at Devise some time back; they basically built on top of the [*warden*](https://github.com/hassox/warden) middleware. There's a good tutorial about it [here](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication):

> The `Devise` gem is built on top of Warden. Warden is a Rack
>   application, which means that it runs as a separate and standalone
>   module, and is (nearly always) executed before the chief Rails
>   application is invoked.
>
> `Warden` provides the cookie handling that verifies the identity of a
>   logged in user via a (secure) session string, in which the id (primary
>   key) of a particular user is somehow stored and disguised. Warden also
>   provides a hook so your app can deal with users who aren’t currently
>   logged in. These users will either have restricted access, or none at
>   all, except, of course, to sign-in/sign-up pages.

Warden handles user authentication very well. If you need ideas, you can look at how they do it.

[image: [warden]]

--

From a technical perspective, there's absolutely nothing wrong with what you're doing.

However, as pointed out, the problems you may encounter are systemic; validating authentication will need to be consistent, not just once a user sets the `:user_id` session.

Thus, I would do the following:

1. `user_id` should not be kept in a session variable. At least, it should be *encoded* with some sort of salt. (The less people know about your user data structure the better)
2. I would personally look to validate the authentication somehow. Once authenticated, I'd create an `authenticated` token in the session, which I could compare to a stored token (kind of like oAuth).

In respect to the second suggestion, there is an interesting thing you could do. There are [semi-persistent storage solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) (the most popular for Rails being [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis)) which will save DB authentication whilst providing RAM-type data access...

[image]

Redis is basically like a database stored in memory; you use it to store `key: value` pairs (JSON). More importantly, it allows you to create a super lightweight authentication system, saving you the expensive SQL.

```
def user_signed_in?
    return redis.get(current_user.id) ? true : false
end
```

Although a very crude example, it should give you an idea as to how caching and external sources would give you the ability to streamline your queries somewhat.

You'd be able to see if a user has the right token in Redis, providing you with an array of "logged in" users. No DB calls.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this approach. It's important to realize that all you're doing is essentially checking for the *existence* of a session variable - this is not sufficient information to determine whether an actual user is logged in. You'll need to query the database to determine whether this user actually exists in the system.

Also, as other commenters have pointed out, more often than not, you'll need the current user model within the lifecycle of the request so the approach described in the tutorial sets you up nicely for that.

Comment: Even then, it wouldn't show that they were logged in, you'd need some sort of token to compare, right?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm assuming based on OP's question that the session variable is set upon successful authentication, in which case using the session variable to successfully find the user on subsequent requests would indeed indicate that the user is logged in.